# Unable to resolve mapper issue using Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have two classes in my code except one data member everything is same. But, not getting how to resolve this issue using Automapper. Can someone please throw some light on this.

```
Class A{ public string Id; public List Values; };

Class B{ public string Id; public List Items; };

Class C{ public string Value; public string Name; public string Dept; };
```

`CreateMap<A, B>();` - This is giving following error while doing unit test, Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type

Comment: Have you configued auto mapper in your application? See [this](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html) page for more information

Answer (score 0):

Explicit AutoMapper Property Mapping

```
CreateMap<A,B>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Items,
     opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Values));
```

[Reference](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/using-automapper-in-asp.net-core/)